# Recolor Image with Transparent Background

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to recolor (switch colors) in a photo with Python (preferably Python 3). I have a lot of geometrical shapes that have a thin black border, white fill, and a transparent background.

Here is an example input photo.

[image: White Circle]

I would like to be able to generate a randomly colored circle.

I started with this code:

```
start_color = (0,0,0) # white
new_color = (255,255,255) # black
# Open image
shape_img = Image.open('circle_example.png').convert('RGB')
shape_data = np.array(shape_img)
# Replace start color with new color
shape_data[(shape_data == start_color).all(axis = -1)] = new_color
# Convert back to image
final_image = Image.fromarray(shape_data, mode='RGB')
final_image.show()
```

This results in:

[image: final_image]

Is there a way to replace just the white forefront and not the transparent background?  (I realize that the transparent background *appears* white in this question, but if you look at the picture, it is transparent around the circle.)

Answer (score 0):

I did find an answer. I need to import the alpha levels as well.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
start_color = (0, 0, 0, 255) # white
new_color = (255, 255, 255, 255) # black
# Open image
shape_img = Image.open('circle_example.png').convert('RGBA')
shape_data = np.array(shape_img)
# Replace start color with new color
shape_data[(shape_data == start_color).all(axis = -1)] = new_color
# Convert back to image
final_image = Image.fromarray(shape_data, mode='RGBA')
final_image.show()
```

Comment: For anyone wanting to try this:
import numpy as np